# Kafka best multi datacenter solution

Tags: apache-kafka

i have 3 separate kubernetes clusters ( 1 in first dc, 2 in second dc, 3 in third ) and 3 separate kafka clusters ( 1 in first dc, 2 in second dc, 3 in third dc ) same as kubernetes

so in normal mode our applications works on Kubernetes in 1 dc and connect to kafka in first dc, and in case of datacenter failure, we provision services on Kubernetes which working in 2 or 3 dc and connect to kafka cluster in 2 or
3 dc

This 3 datacenter locates in the same city but on different buildings and avg latency between dc is 0.400 ms with very rare spikes up to 1,8ms, so i think of it like AZ in AWS

What the best way to build high availability,high speed kafka cluster in multi-dc mode which can work even if any datacenter going offline?
i think about using broker.rack feature and deploy kafka brokers in this fashion

```
DC1- kafka-01
DC2- kafka-02
DC3- kafka-03
```

then use replication factor =2, so even any kafka ( or dc ) goes offline all data will be here and cluster remains working

Or it's better to use Apache Kafka MirrorMaker and have a separately cluster in each DC? and in case of failure just connect to another kafka cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MirrorMaker isn't bullet proof.

If the latency is low enough, then a stretch cluster is fine (and use `broker.rack` and `client.rack` on producers/consumers). However, you will need some networking solution outside of cluster-local CoreDNS, for example, that can resolve external hosts/services (or don't use Kubernetes to provision Kafka, and use something else like Terraform).

The clients will also need to communicate with the "other DC" since they will pick whichever brokers have the leader partitions.

You will also want to ensure `acks=all` and `min.insync.replicas=2`, assuming `replication.factor >= 3` (rather than 2, ideally) , and `unclean.leader.election=false` to ensure that no data is lost during any one DC failure, and it is durably written.